# pdf word count after specific word

Tags: pdf, word-count

I have multiple pdf-files where I need to count the number of words after a specific title or word occurs in the text. E.g., the given title shows up at the top of the second page in a 2-page document, then only the words on page 2 are counted. Do you know if any of the existing word count programs have already included such a feature?

Many thanks for your help

Chris

Comment: The concept "word" is not part of the PDF specifications, so at best your results could be skewed. At worst, you'd get no words at all.

Comment: In which programming language do you want to do this? You would need a PDF library that can do text extraction, and then when you have extracted the text, you do your word counting. This is assuming that your PDF file isn't doing anything funky. I don't want to go into detail but it is perfectly valid to have a PDF with something that visually looks like text but actually is a lot of gibberish when you try to extract it. If you share your PDF file, people will be able to tell you if text extraction is easy or not.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Basically, the pdf-files contain transcripts of phone calls. No graphics or other graphical content, only text. It is possible to select and copy the text out of the pdf-files, so no OCR is needed.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for command line automatiation then

1. You need to convert PDF to text file first using [pdftotext](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/poppler-utils):

   `$ pdftotext transcript.pdf`
2. Then use the `[wc][2]` utility to count words:

   `$ wc -w transcript.txt`